# how can i perform some action every time as mobile connect to internet

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to check that mobile is online or not.

**if** online then save data to server.

**if** not online save in local Storage and as **Mobile** is become connected to internet submit that data to server and empty the local storage.

so far what i have done

```
    if(navigator.onLine)
    {
       //send data to server logic cause mobile device connected to internet
    }
    else {
       // add data to local storage cause you are not online
     $localStorage.sendData[$localStorage.sendData.length-1].data =localStorage.myData;
     // but as user become connected to internet check that data is available
     // in local storage, then send to server
   }
```

**working on ionic framework...**

Answer (score 0):

You have online/offline events of cordova that you can register. You can set a flag in your code and store the online status and use it as you like later.

See events documentation here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520159/1744702) is also answer of mine about detecting being online with a link to great blog post series about it.